# C++: condition-variable wait

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer, condition-variable

```
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>

std::mutex globalMutex;
std::condition_variable globalCondition;
int global = 0;
int activity = 0;
int CountOfThread = 1; // or more than 1

// just for console display, not effect the problem
std::mutex consoleMutex;

void producer() {
    while (true) {
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(globalMutex);
            while (activity == 0) {
                lock.unlock();
                std::this_thread::yield();
                lock.lock();
            }
            global++;
            globalCondition.notify_one();
        }
        std::this_thread::yield();
    }
}


void customer() {
    while (true) {
        int x;
        {
            std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(globalMutex);
            activity++;
            globalCondition.wait(lock); // <- problem
            activity--;
            x = global;
        }
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(consoleMutex);
            std::cout << x << std::endl;
        }
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));
    }
}


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    for (int i = 0; i < CountOfThread; ++i) {
        std::thread(customer).detach();
    }
    std::thread(producer).detach();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

what i want is to make sure everytime there is a customer thread to get an increased global, expect display like: 1, 2, 3, ..., but what i see is the global value will be increased between wait and activity--, thus, actual display is: 1, 23, 56, 78, ....

I've found out the problem is in wait(), acutully there are 3 steps in wait(), 'unlock, wait, lock', between signaled(wait return) and mutex.lock, it's not a atomic operation, the producer thread may lock mutex before wait() to lock mutex, and the activity is still not zero, so the global will increased, unexpectedly

is there a way to make sure what i expect?

Comment: Congratulations on posting a complete minimal example.  It helps enormously!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find that it helps me to thing in the context of thread. For example, if you were a customer, what are *you* waiting on? By you, I mean in the context of thread. When you think this way, it makes it very simple to code with [monitors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_(synchronization)).

Now, as Martin said, I believe that making repeated called to `thread.yield` is a little scary. That can lead to scary interleavings of the code.

To show an example as to why your code does not work, let's walk through a quick interleaving:

1. Several customers are created, and the one that grabs the lock increase `activity`. Then that thread goes to sleep due to the call to `wait`.
2. Another thread wakes up after the call to `wait` by the initial customer thread. This is because `wait` unlocks the mutex passed into it.
3. That thread acquires `globalMutex` and increases `activity`. Then it waits.
4. Repeat for `CountOfThread` number of threads, as this is entirely possible with multithreaded code.
5. Finally, the producer thread runs, sees `activity == 0`, and unlocks. However, it didn't `notify_one` (i.e. signal). Then it yields. This can lead to undefined and confusing code.

My suggestions:

1. Never call `yield` while waiting on a condition. This can lead to complicated and hard to read invalid monitor code.
2. Think about what condition each thread is waiting on. If different sections of code are waiting on different conditions, create a different lock. Only use one lock for one piece of shared code.
3. Use a different condition variable for different conditions *in certain circumstances*. If the condition is dependent on different data, definitely use a different condition variable.

In your circumstance, the solution is not as complicated as you might think. Use my original suggestion: think in the context of a thread. For example, when the producer thread is running, **it wants to wait when the customer hasn't noticed that `global` has been changed**. When a customer thread is running, **it wants to wait whenever producer hasn't changed `global`**.

Here is an example of the behavior you desire:

```
mutex m;

condition_variable cv;
int global = 0, prev_global = 0;

void producer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

        while (prev_global != global)
        {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }
        prev_global = global++;
        cv.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

void customer()
{
    while (true)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(m);

        while (prev_global == global)
        {
            cv.wait(lock);
        }

        prev_global = global;
        cv.notify_one();
        lock.unlock();
    }
}

int main()
{
    vector<thread> pool;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {   

        pool.push_back(thread (customer));
    }

    pool.push_back(thread (producer));

    for (auto it = pool.begin(); it != pool.end(); ++it)
    {
        it->join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: @Benjamin great, glad I could help! Would you mark the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that when `activity` is > 0, `producer` can loop round grabbing the lock, incrementing global, and notifying the condition variable.  (A notify doesn't have to have a corresponding waiter).

Your repeated calls to `thread.yield` are a bit of a red flag - they mean you are polling, rather than waiting.  I think the solution is that you need *two* condition variables.  producer waits on one until is notified by consumer, consumer waits on the other until it is notified by producer.  I'm not quite sure how you make this work with multiple consumers though.